# MongoDB update element of nested array

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a mongo collection named firma which has one of the document structure as below:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5729af099b3ebf1d0ca7ff05"),
    "musteriler" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "de0bf813-b707-4a8d-afc2-9752e05c3aa5",
            "yetkiliListesi" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "a5e487fa-2034-4817-94f2-3bd837b76284",
                    "ad" : "Burak",
                    "soyad" : "Duman 1",
                    "cepTel" : "3333333333333",
                    "mail" : "asdf@asdf.com"
                }, 
                {
                    "_class" : "com.bisoft.entity.MusteriYetkili",
                    "_id" : "bc4b537d-522a-4c9a-9f67-8ca243e18f46",
                    "ad" : "Ridvan",
                    "soyad" : "ENİŞ",
                    "cepTel" : "222222222222",
                    "mail" : "asdf@asdf.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "defaultTimezone" : "Europe/Istanbul"
    }
```

In the above json, I need to update element of second array(yetkiliListesi) which _id = "a5e487fa-2034-4817-94f2-3bd837b76284"

Since I am using a java application(using mongo java driver and spring boot MongoTemplate) to access it and execute this query :

```
 mongoTemplate.updateFirst(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is("5729af099b3ebf1d0ca7ff05").and("musteriler.yetkiliListesi._id").is("a5e487fa-2034-4817-94f2-3bd837b76284")), 
            new Update().set("musteriler.yetkiliListesi.$", yetkiliDBO), Firma.class);
```

In the above query, yetkiliDBO is a BasicDBObject and its content :

```
yetkiliDBO = { 
    '_class': 'com.bisoft.entity.MusteriYetkili', 
    '_id': "a5e487fa-2034-4817-94f2-3bd837b76284", 
    'ad': 'wer', 
    'soyad': 'xyz', 
    'cepTel': "222222222222",
     mail: "asdf@asdf.com" 
}
```

when execute my query I have an error

```
com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: { "serverUsed" : "192.168.2.250:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 0 , "updatedExisting" : false , "err" : "cannot use the part (musteriler of musteriler.yetkiliListesi.0) to traverse the element
```

What I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the '$' placeholder when traversing nested arrays.

> The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a single value

[source](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays)

I would suggest restructuring your data into separate, less-nested collections.

Comment: You could update an entire 'yetkiliListesi' array:  `new Update().set("musteriler.$.yetkiliListesi", List<yetkiliDBO>)` but I would highly suggest restructuring your data.